# Embedded Twitter Timeline interferes with PHP sessions in Firefox

Tags: php, session, firefox, twitter

This issue affects Firefox only. There are no issues in other browsers.

I have a custom login on my website. It works perfectly until I add the Twitter Timeline Embed code. When that code is added, the PHP session value changes when logging in. On signin.php, a php session value is generated. Upon pressing submit and going to success.php, the session value changes.

What could possibly be causing that and why only in Firefox?

Here is my code:

1.php

```
<?php
session_start();

//Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgeries//
$tokengf = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
$_SESSION['tokengf'] = "$tokengf";
$_SESSION['tokengf_timestamp'] = time();
////
?>
<form action="2.php" method="post"  />
<h3> Enter Your Username:</h3>
<span class="question">What is your username? </span>
<p>
  <label for="username">My username is:<br />
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" size="40" maxlength="85" />
</p>
<input type="hidden" name="tokengf" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['tokengf']; ?>" />
<br />
<input type="submit">
</form>
<!--Twitter Timeline-->
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/gftravelsite" data-widget-id="412977135226081280">Tweets by @gftravelsite</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

And here's the page that gets submitted to:

2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo var_dump($_SESSION) . "<BR>";
echo print_r($_POST);
//Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgeries//
if ($_POST['tokengf'] != $_SESSION['tokengf']) {
echo "<br>post and session token values don't match.";
exit;
}
////
```

The browser output is:

```
array(2) { ["tokengf"]=> &string(32) "2e5b9797a3ba1e0b481f363b585c3bb1" ["tokengf_timestamp"]=> &int(1431234058) }
Array ( [username] => [tokengf] => 9bf4cca211d7a9874d954a434c21ac28 ) 1
post and session token values don't match.
```

The same exact page run using Chrome or IE gives this output as expected:

```
array(2) { ["tokengf"]=> &string(32) "fc28ab43754b40e6941a3f0208257de9" ["tokengf_timestamp"]=> &int(1431234321) } 
Array ( [username] => [tokengf] => fc28ab43754b40e6941a3f0208257de9 ) 1
```

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: I assume you cleared your cache ...

Comment: Yes, cleared cache, deleted cookies, restarted PC.

Comment: This is where the page is located for testing - https://glutenfreetravelsite.com/2015/login/1.php